# Retrieving tag strings POSTed through HTML form

Tags: php, html, parsing, tags

I have this form:

```
<form action="form-receiver.php" method="POST">
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"> 
    #tags: <input type="text" name="tags">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I know PHP can parse input, doing something like this:

```
list($var0, $var1) = sscanf('foo bar', '%s %s');
//$var0 and $var1 is now 'foo' and 'bar'
```

But what if I want to parse upon commas, not space, and also don't know how many variables are input?

PS: If you have suggestions for better ways to tag text input, I'm interested to hear it.

Comment: Why not `explode(', ', $_POST['tags'])`? It will give you a nice little array of all values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Asok said in the comments, [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) is what you need. This will produce an array. An example:

```
$myString = "A, string, to be, exploded.";
$exp = explode(',', $myString);
var_dump($exp);
```

will produce

```
array [4] => (
    0 => "A", 
    1 => "string",
    2 => "to be", 
    3 => "exploded."
);
```

Comment: Required parameter $string missing on line 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

You need `extract` but pay attention to security detailed in PHP manual

Answer (score 0):

You could use the explode function, just like

```
$tagArray = explode(",", $_POST['tags'])
```

It will return an array with the exploded values.

Comment: Note, the user would probably need to `trim` each value in this instance. Subject to user input and field requirements / instructions